# Ubuntu dependency problems after `do-release-upgrade`

Tags: upgrade, package-management, dependencies

I recently performed `do-release-upgrade`, and it appears to have broken some of my packages. I can't properly `apt-get autoremove` or `apt-get upgrade` any more.

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f

...

Errors were encountered while processing:
initscripts
netbase
ntpdate
procps
udev
dmsetup
libdevmapper1.02.1
dbus
consolekit
eject
rsyslog
ifupdown
computer-janitor
grub-common
grub2-common
grub-pc-bin
grub-pc
policykit-1
grub-gfxpayload-lists
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04 LTS"
```

What would you recommend to fix this?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get clean`

Comment: @Mitch Doesn't help. :(

Comment: Is this still a problem?